# String declaration problems c++

Tags: c++, string, header, identifier

I was trying to compile this simple program but whenever I try to compile it it gives me many errors and all are string related errors like "`syntax error:identifier 'string'` " and "`undeclared identifier`" for my string function and variable.
I tried to delete `using namespace std;` and using `std::string` instead but still the same errors occur.
I am using Visual Studio 2017.

```
#include "Animal.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Animal Cat;

    cin.get();
}
```

and thats the `Animal.h`:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();

    void SetAnimalName(string x);
    string GetName();

    void SetAnimalAge(int y);
    int GetAnimalAge();

private:
    string AnimalName;
    int AnimalAge;
};
```

Animal.cpp

```
#include "Animal.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Animal::Animal()
{
    AnimalName = "cat";
    AnimalAge = 3;
    std::cout << "the Animal is: " << AnimalName << std::endl << "its Age is: " << AnimalAge;
}

void Animal::SetAnimalName(string x) {
    AnimalName = x;
}
string Animal::GetName() {
    return AnimalName;
}
void Animal:: SetAnimalAge(int y) {
    AnimalAge = y;
}
int Animal::GetAnimalAge() {
    return AnimalAge;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `#include <string>` in your `Animal.h` which breaks the compilation of your `main.cpp`.

You are also missing `std::string` in your `Animal.h`. As a general rule of thumb, don't use `using namespace std` and stick with prefixing standard library functions with the `std` namespace (`std::string` in your case).

Comment: I just tried to add that but unfortunately nothing has changed :(